# Passing Derived Class to a method which needs to override expecting a base class

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a class A, with an abstract method doAction(BaseClass obj) expecting a param of type BaseClass

```
public class A {
    //....
    abstract void doAction(BaseClass obj);
    //....
}
```

Now, I have another class B which needs to extend A. However, B's doAction method needs to use an object DerivedClass which extends BaseClass.

```
public class B extends class A {
     //..
     void doAction(DerivedClass obj) {
          obj.callMethodAvailableOnlyInDerivedClass();
      }

 }
```

How do I handle this situation where I need to pass param of type DerivedClass to the method to be overridden while it is expecting a BaseClass ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You make the base class generic:

```
public class A<T extends BaseClass> {
    //....
    abstract void doAction(T obj);
    //....
}
```

and the subclass parameterized with the derived class:

```
public class B extends A<DerivedClass> {
     //..
     void doAction(DerivedClass obj) {
         obj.callMethodAvailableOnlyInDerivedClass();
     }
}
```

Without generics, it's not possible because B would break the contract of A: A accepts any kind of BaseClass, but you retrict B to only accept a specific subclass. This does not respect the [Liskov principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: +1 for the Liskov principle. First time I hear about it, thanks!

Comment: And if you have a bunch of these methods acting on different objects?!

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
public abstract class A<T extends BaseClass> {
//....
abstract void doAction(T obj);
//....
}


public class B extends class A<DerivedClass> {
 //..
 void doAction(DerivedClass obj) {
      obj.callMethodAvailableOnlyInDerivedClass();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no [Contra-Variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) of parameters in java, since it is not safe.

Assume you have `A a = new B();`

And then you invoke `a.doAction(new BaseClass())` What will happen?

It will cause a run time error, since `B` does not know "what to" with a `BaseClass`. java wants to avoid it - so there is no covariance of parameters.