# Passing in a sub-class to a method but having the super class as the parameter?

Tags: java, oop

I have an abstract class `Vehicle` with 2 implemented subclasses `RedVehicle` and `YellowVehicle`.

In another class I have a `List<Vehicle>` containing instances of both subclasses.
I want to be able to pass into a method a class type and then use that type to decide which set of objects I want to do something to in the `List`.

Since `Class` is generic I should parameterise it with something, however putting the parameter as the parent class `Vehicle` stops the calling code working since `exampleMethod` is now expecting a type of Vehicle, not a subclass of `RedVehicle` or `YellowVehicle`.

I feel there should be a clean way to do this so what would be the correct way to implement the functionality?

n.b. I don't necessarily have to pass in the `Class` type, if there are better suggestions I'd be happy to try those.

Calling code:

```
service.exampleMethod(RedVehicle.class);
service.exampleMethod(YellowVehicle.class);
```

Fields/Method:

```
//List of vehicles
//Vehicle has 2 subclasses, RedVehicle and YellowVehicle
private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

//Having <Vehicle> as the Class parameter stops the calling code working
public void exampleMethod(Class<Vehicle> type) 
{
    for(Vehicle v : vehicles)
    {
        if(v.getClass().equals(type))
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
public <T extends Vehicle> void exampleMethod(Class<T> type)
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Is there a special name for having the generic type before the return type/a link to a general source would be nice. I'll try and tomorrow and accept if it works thanks.

Comment: have a look at oracle's generics introduction or angelika langer's java generics FAQ. +1 for mprivat's direct solution.

Comment: @DaveBall Thanks for the angelika langer suggesetion, I'm aware of generics as a concept and have used them but have never looked at them in depth, this looks like a great in-depth discussion of them. The link for anyone else interested: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Comment: A little elaboration of this answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9421315/1276636)

Comment: @Peanut They are called generic methods

Comment: I understand the Class<T> part in the argument to support type Vehicle. What I now understand is that if a method uses a generic <T> in its argument, it needs to be added to the method  syntax structure before the return type.of the method too

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)?

That way you

- don't need type tokens
- let dynamic dispatch handle the case distinction (instead of `if(v.getClass().equals(type))`)
- are more flexible (following [OCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle))

---

In detail:

your abstract class `Vehicle` gets a method `accept(Visitor v)`, with the subclasses implementing it by calling the appropriate method on `v`.

```
public interface Visitor {
  visitRedVehicle(RedVehicle red);
  visitYellowVehicle(YellowVehicle yellow);
}
```

Using a visitor:

```
public class Example {

  public void useYellowOnly() {
    exampleMethod(new Visitor() {
        visitRedVehicle(RedVehicle red) {};
        visitYellowVehicle(YellowVehicle yellow) {
             //...action
        });
  }
  public void exampleMethod(Visitor visitor){
      for(Vehicle v : vehicles) {
          v.accept(visitor);
      }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found this syntax to be working as expected:

```
public void exampleMethod(Class<? extends Vehicle> type)
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works and got me where I wanted to go. I thought I would add this just to make it clearer to anyone who might need it.

In this case RevisedExposure is a sub-class of Exposure. I need to call GetMetadata() with a list of either of these, which results in the same result set.

```
private async Task<List<Metadata>> GetMetadata<T>(List<T> exposures) where T : Exposure
```

Now I can call this method from two places with different versions of the list like this.

```
var metadata = await GetExposureMetadata(revisions);
```

or

```
var metadata = await GetExposureMetadata(exposures);
```

works great!