# Overload method with subclasses as parameters but have the method called as the superclass

Tags: java, overloading, subclass, extending-classes

I have an abstract class `Animal`, with two extending classes, `Dog` and `Cat`.

```
public abstract class Animal {
...
}
public class Dog extends Animal {
...
}
public class Cat extends Animal {
...
}
```

In another class, I have an `ArrayList<Animal> animals` that contains instances of both `Cat` and `Dog`.

In the class with the `ArrayList<Animal>`, I want to be able to overload a method `doSomething()` with either `Dog d` or `Cat c` as the parameters, but still be able to call them from the ArrayList of Animals. As follows:

```
public void aMethod(){
    ArrayList<Animals> animals = getTheAnimals();
    for (Animal a : animals){
        doSomething(a);
    }
}
public void doSomething(Dog a){
//a is an object of type dog
}
public void doSomething(Cat a){
//a is an object of type cat
}
```

Essentially, each method is acting as a 'selector' for which `type` of animal is being received by the method.

When trying as above, I get the following compilation error:

> error: no suitable method found for doSomething(Animal)

I know I could use something like `instanceOf` or `a.getClass().equals(type)`, but I have read that this is bad practice.
This question differs slightly from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056350/passing-in-a-sub-class-to-a-method-but-having-the-super-class-as-the-parameter), as I want two separate methods, each with a different parameter.

**EDIT:** I am going to avoid using the Visitor Pattern as I don't think it really fits well into my actual implementation. Will move the doSomething() method into each class, and refactor to ensure this makes logical sense (each class performing actions that it should be responsible for). Thanks.

Comment: Just have the `doSomething` method in the abstract class so `Dog` and `Cat` have to implement it.  Then, while looping, just call `doSomething` and it'll call the implementation specific object.

Comment: If some one write `Bird extends Animal` and put `Bird bird = new Bird()` into the list. Which method should get called?

Comment: `doSomething()` should probably be in `Anmial`, and overridden in each sublcass.  So instead of `doSomething(a)` make it `a.doSomething()`.

Comment: It is not possible since the method to be invoked is chosen at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes instanceof and getclass would make your class dependent upon specific types and using such practices are not too good.

But by having methods accepting `Dog` or `Cat` you again end up depending upon the concrete specific implementation.

Better way is Define method in `Animal` interface `performAction()` . Provide implementation in both `Dog` and `Cat`.  Now iterate your List of Animals and just invoke `performAction()` and polymorphically as per actual instance either Dog or Cat implemented method would be called. Later even if there is another implementation of Animal added in code you need not modify your code.

This way you would be having Dog related logic in Dog class, Cat related logic in Cat class and not in any outside different class. This will help in respecting OCP and SRP (Open close and Single Responsibility principles).

Also in case you wish to perform behavior later and your case is such that you know your implementations are fixed and want the using code to inject behavior later then I would recommend `Visitor` pattern, but still I feel this should not be abused, (design pattern are often not used but abused) sometime we force a pattern when not needed. Visitor pattern uses polymorphic to dispatch the first call to specific instance from where second dispatch calls the overloaded methods in class implementing the Visitor interface. (name can be different, I have mentioned Visitor to imply class implementing the concept of visitor) . Go for Visitor pattern like implementation  only if needed and normal above polymorphic based approach do not fit the situation.

Comment: This along with @Dan 's code example help the most. Thanks. 
I initially didn't want to move the doSomething() method into the Dog and Cat classes as it didn't really make much logical sense in terms of what the classes were actually doing, but I will refactor to better reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating in your client method and calling doSomething(), keep doSomething() as a method in your abstract class, that way you can change the way you want in Cat or Dog.

```
public void aMethod(){
  ArrayList<Animals> animals = getTheAnimals();
    for (Animal a : animals){
       a.doSomething();
     }
  }

abstract Animal {
   doSomething();
}

Dog extends Animal {


  doSomething() {
    //Dog stuff
  }

}

Cat extends Animal {

   doSomething() {
     //cat stuff
   }

}
```

Comment: Note that code only answers are generally voted down; please include a description on how this solves the problem stated in the question.

Comment: Add description along with code + include in your answer that Animal defines the doSomething(). In your code it looks Dog and Cat have doSomething method but it does not tell anything as how Animal type reference is able to invoke it. Also in your question have Dog and Cat implement the Animal Interface.

Comment: Got it. added it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Move method into `Abstract` class so each implementation has to make its own version of the method.

```
public abstract class Animal {

  public abstract void doSomething();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
   public void doSomething(){
       System.out.println("Bark");
   }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
   public void doSomething(){
       System.out.println("Meow");
   }
}
```

Then in the other Class you mentioned above you can do the following:

```
  public void vocalize(){
      List<Animal> animals = getTheAnimals();
      for (Animal animal : animals){
         animal.doSomething();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a double dispatch : a runtime type provided by java + a  runtime parameter type that you have to implement. The visitor pattern is a way to do that.

Introduce a `Visitable` interface, implements it in `Animal` to make it accept a visitor.
Then introduce a Visitor.  You can implement it with or without interface according to your requirement.
Simple version (by coupling the visitor to the current class) that keeps the actual logic of your code :

```
public interface Visitable{
   void accept(MyClassWithSomeAnimals myClassWithSomeAnimals);
}

public abstract class Animal implements Visitable{
...
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
...
  void accept(MyClassWithSomeAnimals myClassWithSomeAnimals){
     myClassWithSomeAnimals.doSomething(this);
  }

}
public class Cat extends Animal {
...
  void accept(MyClassWithSomeAnimals myClassWithSomeAnimals){
     myClassWithSomeAnimals.doSomething(this);
  }
}
```

And update `MyClassWithSomeAnimals` in this way :

```
public void aMethod(){
    ArrayList<Animals> animals = getTheAnimals();
    for (Animal a : animals){
         a.accept(this);
    }
}
```

This solution works but it has a drawback. It exposes `MyClassWithSomeAnimals` to `Animal` subclasses while These need only to have a way to invoke the visitor method, not any public methods.
So a improvement would be to introduce a `Visitor` interface  to limit to `doSomething()` what Animal know of the visitor :

```
public interface Visitor{
  void doSomething(Dog dog);
  void doSomething(Cat cat);
}
```

So make `MyClassWithSomeAnimals` implement it and change Visitable class/concrete classes to use it :

```
public interface Visitable{
  void accept(Visitor visitor);
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
...
  void accept(Visitor visitor){
     visitor.doSomething(this);
  }

}
public class Cat extends Animal {
...
  void accept(Visitor visitor){
     visitor.doSomething(this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an important rule in Java that defines most of how Inheritance, Interface and Abstract classes work - A superclass reference variable can hold a subclass object.Hence, there are a few ways to overcome your error.

1. If your `Dog` and `Cat` classes are concrete classes for the `Animal` abstract class, then you can simply define one `doSomething(Animal animal)` and the method will work.
2. You can try making your `doSomething` method generic. Such as
   `public <T> void doSomething(<T extends Animal> animal)`
3. Or you can define a doSomething abstract method in Animal and have the subclasses provide their own implementations for it, as suggested by Andrew S. in the above answer.